# An error occurred when accessing the keychain

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

An error occurred when accessing the keychain. iOS 9.3.3, when the app run from xcode (debug) it works fine, but if the same app which is already in the device, I try to run it directly, it shows error like above, anybody know how to resolve it?

It works if the pod is only firebase
If I just add another pod, it will fail like above

It runs without issues in iOS 8 and iOS 10 simulator

Xcode 8, swift 3

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You have to enable Keychain sharing for the target that you are working on.
In your xcode open project setting then open capabilities tab and enable keysharing.
Firebase will work like a charm!. Screen shot is attached.

[Enable Keychain Sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAoQc.png)

Answer (score 0):

yea Fazal Ellahi, you correct solve problem for me